# Format JSON encoded string into more human readable in Silverstripe

Tags: php, arrays, json, silverstripe

In the Silverstripe website, the user submits a form and it gets stored on the CMS for content managers to see the submitted forms.

The functionality works, but the problem is that I have `$data` returned in a PHP array and I want to output it to the CMS.

The only way I figured out is to convert it to JSON, but then it just outputs a JSON string, and I would like to have something like HTML table to make it more human readable. How would I do this?

My code so far is:

```
// converts array to jason, on controller
$SubmitedResult->SerialisedForm = Convert::array2json($data);

// $db on dataobject
private static $db = array(
  'SerialisedForm' => 'Text',
);

// JSON string received below
{"url":"\/test\/test-test\/testSubmit","Name":"Tom","Email":"tom@gmail.com","Phone":"564456","SecurityID":"c5efe841e26d6d088dd94dfcfe76f6ec80acac86","action_submit":"Submit"}
```

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete, verifiable example as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: hey posted the JSON string I receive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you'd want to build a `DataObject` where you store your submitted form data. It seems like you already have that, but you use it to store all the data in a field called `SerialisedForm`. I suggest you create a separate field for all your form fields instead.

Example:

```
class FormSubmission extends DataObject
{
    private static $db = [
        'Name' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'Email' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'Phone' => 'Varchar(64)'
    ];

    // The summary_fields ensure that your fields directly show up in the GridField
    private static $summary_fields = [
        'Name' => 'Name',
        'Email' => 'Email',
        'Phone' => 'Phone'
    ];
}
```

Then in your form submit handler, you do:

```
public function testSubmit($data, $form)
{
    $submittedResult = FormSubmission::create();
    $form->saveInto($submittedResult);
    $submittedResult->write();
    // redirect back or somewhere else…
}
```

In the CMS you can use a `GridField` on your Page or a `ModelAdmin` instance to view the submissions.